# Segmentation fault 11 when code coverage is turned on in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, xctest

While I am running unit tests with XCTest in Swift, they run fine when code coverage is turned off. However once I try to enable code coverage, I have a failed build/test with 4 classes giving the following error message: **Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11**.

Comment: Could it be an issue with certificates or build targets? I found this source saying that was the issue when getting seg fault from archiving. Maybe try rebuilding certificates? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731198/swift-segmentation-fault-when-compiling-for-archive-from-ios-7

Comment: Please, provide more details

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me (as all the other suggestions did not work in my case).  I was getting a segmentation fault 11 on a particular Swift class when trying to run unit tests with code coverage turned ON.  It turns out that we had a ternary expression on a class's property like so:

```
let cellBorder : CGFloat = MyHelperClass.isIPad() ? 10.0 : 6.0
```

Making it a lazy var fixed the problem:

```
lazy var cellBorder : CGFloat = MyHelperClass.isIPad() ? 10.0 : 6.0
```

To be clear, the code compiled and worked fine **until we tried turning on code coverage**.
I also found this [Open Radar](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6121096961064960) and [this guy's post](http://rolandleth.com/code-coverage-issues-for-swift-projects) that outlined the solution.  Appears to be an Apple bug.

Comment: I had the same problem. `lazy` solves, but this will also solve it:

`let cellBorder : CGFloat = MyHelperClass.isIPad() ? CGFloat(10.0) : CGFloat(6.0)`

Answer (score 2):

Without code, build settings, etc. it's hard to say for sure but one thing you should check is to make sure that you are using a `@testable` import flag in your unit test classes.

For instance with a project named `MyApp` at the top of your unit test class you would include with the following import `@testable import MyApp`.

You also want to check to ensure that you've followed the process for enabling coverage all the way through. That information is documented on Apple's developer portal:

[Code Coverage | Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/07-code_coverage.html)

Comment: I have followed all those steps already. If the segmentation fault appears when the code coverage is introduced, what does would be a general suggestion about the introduction of it to the project to go about debugging or researching into a bit deeper than I currently am at?

Answer (score 0):

See this bug report on similar issue. https://bugs.swift.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SR-1825

I got the same error when implementing a protocol which required an optional variable that I implemented as a lazy var.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was building through the cli running the xcodebuild command with Release configuration and no provitionings configured, when i switched to Debug config build and tests worked just fine