# Segmentation fault 11 when using code coverage with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing, xctest

While I am running unit tests with XCTest in Swift, they run fine when code coverage is turned off. However once I try to enable code coverage, I have a failed build/test, giving the following error message: `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: looks like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634486/segmentation-fault-11-when-code-coverage-is-turned-on-in-swift) is the same and has some activity